# NullPointerException with Hibernate FETCH JOIN

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I get a NullPointerException when executing the list method on a hibernate query. This is my code:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

String hql = "SELECT g FROM DeviceGroup g JOIN FETCH g.devices";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<DeviceGroup> list = query.list();

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();

return list;
```

The relationship is defined like this:

Device:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private DeviceGroup deviceGroup;
```

DeviceGroup:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "deviceGroup")
private Set<Device> devices;
```

If I leave out the fetch join, the list method succeeds, but lazy fetching results in a StackOverflowException. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had a hashCode implementation on the entities that caused an infinite loop. It's still quite a strange behavior to throw a NullPointerException in this case...

Answer (score 2):

Try with `identifier d` on `g.devices` ,

```
SELECT g FROM DeviceGroup g JOIN FETCH g.devices d
```